# App installation data (from google play and apple store)

Tags: api, app-store, installation, google-play

As part of a project in my workplace -
I'm searching the web for a way to get the daily installations per device
(note that the data from google analytics is irrelevant for us as they give back the
amount of installations and not installations per device -
in case a user installs, removes and installs the app again they regard it as 2 installations while google play developer console display this as 1 installation).

So far I found out that the google play developer console contains the data we need,
but the only way I could get that data is by manually downloading a csv file and parsing it.

This is not good enough for us as we MUST automate the download process and get that data without any human.

I'll note that we are using .net technology and from what I've red we can't get that data with the
beta API library which google supplies for the google play developer console.

P.S. we have to do the same with the apple app store

P.S. 2 we can't use a 3rd party code/service

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's too late now, but maybe it can help someone else.

Google Play Store:

First of all, you need GCP account
"Reports are available from Google Cloud Storage. Reports are generated daily and accumulated in monthly CSV files. They are stored in a private Google Cloud Storage bucket for your Google Play Developer account."

Second point, you need bucket ID
"Find your reporting bucket ID on one of your Download reports pages, near the bottom of the page.
Your bucket ID begins with: pubsite_prod_rev (Example: pubsite_prod_rev_01234567890987654321)."

and you can follow the steps below

Step 1: Create a service account
Sign in to the Google Developers Console (console.developers.google.com).
If you already have a project, use the drop-down to select a project. If you don't have a project listed or want to create a new one, click Create project.
Select the Menu icon Menu icon > Permissions > Service accounts > Create service account.
Follow the on-screen instructions and select Create.
Copy the email address listed.
Example: accountName@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Step 2: Add the service account on your Play Console
Sign in to your Play Console.
Select Settings Settings > User accounts & rights > Invite new user.
Paste or type the email address associated with your service account.
Based on the types of reports needed, select permissions.
For example, if you need access to financial reports, select “View financial reports.”
Click Add user. Your service account will be added to your account.

Step 3: Fetch reports using an API call
Install the API client library for your preferred code language.
Configure the code performing the API call to use OAuth2 server-to-server authentication and to request permission to the OAuth2 scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only).
Issue authenticated API calls to fetch reports.

To learn more, follow link: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

More information here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870

Answer (score 0):

Google Developer console provides two options. 1) number of downloads. 2) No of total devices currently using your app..

I hope 2nd option will help you in the case..

Or you can also ask user for one time registration

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to automate the process of getting the 2nd option's data - I'm already getting it manually.

Comment: @GrizzlyMcBear, I have a similar requirement, will it be possible to share some details on how you are able to get the installation details via automated process - TIA